# Is it possible to stringify a C macro that contains a comma?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Say I have this:

```
#define CAKE     , something
```

and the result I want is `", something"`. Can it be done?

The following doesn't work in gcc:

```
#define MAKE_STRING(x)  #x
#define STRING(x)       MAKE_STRING(x)

STRING(CAKE)
```

The compiler thinks I'm passing two arguments into MAKE_STRING() and balks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your preprocessor supports variadic macros, `__VA_ARGS__` will do the trick:

```
#define CAKE     , something

#define MAKE_STRING(...)  #__VA_ARGS__
#define STRING(x)       MAKE_STRING(x)

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", STRING(CAKE) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I actually did was changed MAKE_STRING() to #__VA_ARGS__

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CAKE     (, something)
```

please have a try.